# sort an array of objects by date

Tags: typescript

I am trying to sort an array of objects with each object containing a date

Here is the array

```js
array = {
  data: [{
      grievance_nature: "Nature Two"
      grievance_nature_id: 19
      date: "2019-01-19 06:53:20"
    },
    {
      grievance_nature: "Nature Two"
      grievance_nature_id: 19
      date: "2019-01-30 06:53:20"
    },
    {
      grievance_nature: "Nature Two"
      grievance_nature_id: 19
      date: "22019-01-21 19:30:32"
    },
    {
      grievance_nature: "Nature Two"
      grievance_nature_id: 19
      date: "2019-01-28 06:53:20"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to sort the array in order of date with the most recent one. If a date is same it should be sorted on time.

I tried out these functions which didn't give me results

```js
array.data.sort(function(a, b) {
  var c = new Date(a.date);
  var d = new Date(b.date);
  return c - d;
});
```

The above solution didn't give me any result

The required form of array is this:

```js
array = {
  data: [{
      grievance_nature: "Nature Two"
      grievance_nature_id: 19
      date: "2019-01-30 06:53:20"
    },
    {
      grievance_nature: "Nature Two"
      grievance_nature_id: 19
      date: "2019-01-28 06:53:20"
    } {
      grievance_nature: "Nature Two"
      grievance_nature_id: 19
      date: "22019-01-21 19:30:32"
    },
    {
      grievance_nature: "Nature Two"
      grievance_nature_id: 19
      date: "2019-01-19 06:53:20"
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: your array is the data property within the array object. did you try `array.data.sort(...` ?

Comment: yes I did with array.data.sort but dint get result

Comment: Your data has property `grievance_reg_date` but not `date`. TypeScript should be able to mark your code as error.

Comment: even if it is date it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect:

[playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0Aconst%20array%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20data%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20grievance_nature%3A%20%22Nature%20Two%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20grievance_nature_id%3A%2019%2C%0A%20%20%20%20grievance_reg_date%3A%20%222019-01-19%2006%3A53%3A20%22%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20grievance_nature%3A%20%22Nature%20Two%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20grievance_nature_id%3A%2019%2C%0A%20%20%20%20grievance_reg_date%3A%20%222019-01-30%2006%3A53%3A20%22%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20grievance_nature%3A%20%22Nature%20Two%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20grievance_nature_id%3A%2019%2C%0A%20%20%20%20grievance_reg_date%3A%20%2222019-01-21%2019%3A30%3A32%22%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20grievance_nature%3A%20%22Nature%20Two%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20grievance_nature_id%3A%2019%2C%0A%20%20%20%20grievance_reg_date%3A%20%222019-01-28%2006%3A53%3A20%22%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%5D%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aarray.data.sort(function(a%2C%20b)%20%7B%0A%20%20var%20c%20%3D%20new%20Date(a.date)%3B%0A%20%20var%20d%20%3D%20new%20Date(b.date)%3B%0A%20%20return%20c%20-%20d%3B%0A%7D)%3B%0A)

Use any editor with TypeScript support (such as VSCode) should guide you and fix your problem.

[working playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0Aconst%20array%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20data%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20grievance_nature%3A%20%22Nature%20Two%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20grievance_nature_id%3A%2019%2C%0A%20%20%20%20grievance_reg_date%3A%20%222019-01-19%2006%3A53%3A20%22%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20grievance_nature%3A%20%22Nature%20Two%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20grievance_nature_id%3A%2019%2C%0A%20%20%20%20grievance_reg_date%3A%20%222019-01-30%2006%3A53%3A20%22%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20grievance_nature%3A%20%22Nature%20Two%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20grievance_nature_id%3A%2019%2C%0A%20%20%20%20grievance_reg_date%3A%20%2222019-01-21%2019%3A30%3A32%22%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20grievance_nature%3A%20%22Nature%20Two%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20grievance_nature_id%3A%2019%2C%0A%20%20%20%20grievance_reg_date%3A%20%222019-01-28%2006%3A53%3A20%22%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%5D%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aconsole.log(array.data.sort(function(a%2C%20b)%20%7B%0A%20%20var%20c%20%3D%20new%20Date(a.grievance_reg_date)%3B%0A%20%20var%20d%20%3D%20new%20Date(b.grievance_reg_date)%3B%0A%20%20return%20c.getTime()%20-%20d.getTime()%3B%0A%7D))%0A)